# Can witchcraft/sorcery affect not only "physical" things, but also one's emotions/thoughts?

Tags: sorcery-magic-kishuf

There are examples of the Torah of witchcraft being performed to change physical realities (e.g Serpent with Paroh's sorcerers, blood in the river, Bilaam flying, etc.), can sorcery/witchcraft also change someone's emotions or thoughts?

Note: this question is going according to the commentators that accept kishuf etc. as being real.

**Edit:**
I was thinking about it a bit, and it's a bit of a stretch, but when Rabbi Shimon and the שד conspired to possess the Roman Emperor's daughter *might* qualify here, considering the sorcery discussion in Sanhedrin 67a.

Comment: Is this question on-topic? Questions about ["general knowledge (science, etc.) as it relates directly to Judaism"](/help/on-topic) are on-topic, but I don't see how this question is about witchcraft *as it relates directly to Judaism*.

Comment: @msh210 In Sanhedrin 67a or (b?) there is a lengthy discussion about the various types of kishuf and their differences. Is that on topic?

Comment: _Maseches Sanhedrin_ is on-topic. I see no mention of _Sanhedrin_ in this question.

Comment: But I guess this is on-topic, since it explicitly asks about effecting emotions and thoughts *because those are excluded from the examples of* kishuf *in the Torah*.

Comment: Do you mean particularly witchcraft  or all forms of spiritual powers (such as kabbalistic)? In Sefer raziel there is a recipe for a love potion

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is any mekor that you can change a person's mood through kishuf.

This would seem to be a challenge to bechirah if it was possible.

It would also be a challenge to halacha, ha'adam muad le'olam etc.

Comment: Just curious, are you that familiar with the entire body of Torah literature that you can assert that no such source exists? Nor do I see that as being a challenge to Bechira at all. There are many things which can impinge on one's free choice, and don't undermine Creation.